# retreiving status of ThreadPoolExecutor for flask app

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, flask

this is my first real attempt and multi-threading and ThreadPoolExecutor seemed simple enough to start with. I'm sure I have an endless list of bad things I'm doing here that sort of work but shouldn't and I'm open to hearing all of it. Where I'm hard stuck is how exactly to interact with this from my flask application. I want to be able to submit some task then use ajax calls to periodically check the status and get results. Maybe this is poor design but I figured this threading service could live and die with each request since requests will be limited in quantity.

If it matters I'm using gunicorn for development and nginx for production.

From inside Flask app

```
from somefile import threaded_get
from threading import Thread
@app.route("/dothing", methods=["POST"])
def dothing():
    ... 
    session['thread'] = Thread(target=threaded_get, args=(session['somevar'], session['someothervar']))
    session.get('thread').daemon = True
    session.get('thread').start()
    return 'started things'

@app.route("/getthingstatus", methods=["GET"])
def getthingstatus():
   session['thread'].get_status_results()????? #Here
   if(everythingisdone):
      session['thread'].stop()???
```

threaded_get

```
import os
import sys
import concurrent.futures
import time
import pexpect

workers = []

def get(host):
    #pexpect things
    return result

def get_status_results():
    returndata = []
    for w in workers:
        returndata.append(w[0], w[1]._state, w[1]._result)
    return returndata

def threaded_get(hosts, command):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as pool:
        for h in hosts:
            workers.append([h, pool.submit(get, h, command)])
        while(len(list(filter(lambda w:(not w[1]._result), workers))) > 0):
            time.sleep(1)
        pool.shutdown()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design is poor, you can use a class with a static pool and map your request to one of your pools and keep checking the status for the same.

job_pool.py

```
class MyJobPool:
   def __init__(max_jobs=100):
     self.max_jobs = max_jobs
     # Add more code
   def create_job():
     # TODO
     # returns a string job id
     pass
   def run(job_id):
    # run this job using pool
    pass
  def get_job_status(job_id):
     # check thread pool executor status
     pass
```

app.py

```
jobPool = MyJobPool(50)

from somefile import threaded_get
from threading import Thread
@app.route("/dothing", methods=["POST"])
def dothing():
    # TODO
    job_id = jobPool.create_job()
    session['job_id'] = job_id
    jobPool.run(job_id)
    return 'started things'

@app.route("/getthingstatus", methods=["GET"])
def getthingstatus():
   status = jobPool.get_job_status( session['job_id'])
   # do something based on the status
   return status
```

Comment: Thanks, coupled with zmq this worked beautifully.